# Heaped up tikz figure-how to fix

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikz-styles

My problem is: The figure looks ok on Geogebra, but after exporting to Tikz code and importing to LaTex, it is ugly and have some heaped up between point, lines, and the name of the point or line.

Here is the picture on Geogebra: [image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.5]
\draw (2,2)-- (0,-2);
\draw (0,-2)-- (8,-2);
\draw (8,-2)-- (10,2);
\draw (10,2)-- (2,2);
\draw (2,2)-- (2.94,0.52);
\draw (2.94,0.52)-- (0,-2);
\draw (2.94,0.52)-- (9.25,0.5);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (2,2) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.16,2.18) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (0,-2) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (0,-2.24) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (8,-2) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (8.1,-2.24) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (10,2) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (10.16,2.18) node {$D$};
\fill [color=black] (2.94,0.52) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.18,0.84) node {$X$};
\fill [color=black] (9.25,0.5) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (9.4,0.36) node {$Y=Z$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, how can I fix it? How can I place the points' names properly as in Geogebra?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually, in every "translation" process, some information gets lost. For this kind of simple drawings, I think you can do better with pure TikZ code since you can control everything; the quickest fix to this, I believe is to add the option `[right]` or `[left]` to the `node {$Y=Z$}`.

Comment: Do we have option [up] or [down] also?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh you can use `[above]` or `[below]`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get the same output by exporting from Geogebra. You'll have to edit the source manually.

I've used node anchors to put labels next to the desired points. See section *17.5 Positioning Nodes* in the TikZ & PGF manual (version 3.0.0).

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.5]
\draw (2,2)-- (0,-2);
%\draw (0,-2)-- (8,-2);
\draw (8,-2)-- (10,2);
\draw (10,2)-- (2,2);
\draw (2,2)-- (2.94,0.5);
\draw (2.94,0.5)-- (0,-2);
\draw (2.94,0.5)-- (9.25,0.5);

\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (2,2) circle (0.5pt);
\fill [color=black] (0,-2) circle (0.5pt);
\fill [color=black] (8,-2) circle (0.5pt);
\fill [color=black] (10,2) circle (0.5pt);
\fill [color=black] (2.94,0.5) circle (0.5pt);
\fill [color=black] (9.25,0.5) circle (0.5pt);

\draw[color=black, anchor=south] (2,2) node {$A$};
\draw[color=black, anchor=north] (0,-2) node {$B$};
\draw[color=black, anchor=north] (8,-2) node {$C$};
\draw[color=black, anchor=south] (10,2) node {$D$};
\draw[color=black, anchor=south west] (2.94,0.5) node {$X$};
\draw[color=black, anchor=west] (9.25,0.5) node {$Y=Z$};
\draw (0,-2) -- node[above] {h.3a} ++(8,0);
\end{scriptsize}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: :Thank you very much but everything looks inversely, right? I think A is placed at the north of the point when we look at the picture but the code says south :D

Comment: The problem is sometimes "anchor" places the label too far from the point. So, what is the effective way to place the label?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh You can refine node placement using the `positioning` TikZ library: `\node at (1,1) [above=2mm, draw] {above};`. This will place the text "above" above the coordinate (1, 1) by two millimeters. About your first comment, I can't explain node placement better than the official TikZ & PGF documentation, please see section *17.5 Positioning Nodes* ([http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)).